# PHP Error: Upload FILES failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

** After running my code this error appears: failed to open stream: failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections.**

```
$sqlstr = "INSERT INTO imagens VALUES (NULL,?,?,?)";

$sql = self::$pdo->prepare($sqlstr);
        
$arr = array();
$arrExp = explode(".", $file["name"]);
$endArr = end($arrExp);
$ext = strtolower($endArr);
$hashName = md5(time()) .".". $ext;

$destination_path = INCLUDE_PATH."images/upload/".$hashName;
move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $destination_path);

array_push($arr, $nome, $hashName, $idImg);
$sql->execute($arr);

echo "<script>alert('Imagem adicionada com sucesso!');</script>";
```

Comment: What is the content of `$file['tmp_name']` when calling `move_uploaded_file()`?

Comment: the content of ```$file['tmp_name']``` is a image

Comment: My guess is that `$file['tmp_name']` does not contain an image, it probably contains a file name. The error message refers to the HTTP wrapper, I was wondering whether `$file['tmp_name']` could start with `http://` or for that matter whether `INCLUDE_PATH` could start with it. That is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

consegui resolver:

Na parte onde está escrito $destination = INCLUDE_PATH, eu removi o INCLUDE_PATH pois o diretorio estaria no mesmo local do meu host então só coloquei o nome do diretorio